# Searching dictionary using prefixes

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

For example given a dictionary

```
dic={"abcd":2, "abce":2, "abgg":2}
```

I need to search the dictionary using the prefix of the string, i.e., if given "abc", it will return me two entries

```
{"abcd":2, "abce":2}
```

an obvious way:

```
dic1={}
for k, v in dic.items():
    if(k.startswith("abc")):
        dic1[k]=v
```

Is it possible to do it more efficiently?

Comment: You can't do with `dict`. You can use a [trie](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=trie&submit=search).

Comment: Well, you can do it with a `dict`, but then you lose `O(1)` lookup - a trie is certainly more efficient for this case.

Comment: What if there is an entry `"abc": 5`?

Comment: Maybe trie is not helpful enough for this issue, in the OP's example, `Trie.children('ab')` and `Trie.children('abcd')` will not return any thing but `k.startswith` will.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
>>> d={"abcd":2, "abce":2, "abgg":2}
>>> { k:v for k,v in d.iteritems() if k.startswith('abc') }
{'abcd': 2, 'abce': 2}
>>>
```